# how to post on Linkedin group with javascript?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am trying to post on my group using JavaScript API but getting error Access to write groups denied (403 Forbidden)
How can I solve this error?

```
IN.API.Raw("/groups/" + 10356772 + "/posts?format=json") 
.method("POST") 
.body(JSON.stringify({"title": "hi title", "summary": "hi summary"})) .result(onSuccess) 
.error(onError);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where are you trying to run this script? In the actual Linkedin page under the dev tools console?

You should take a deeper look at the headers sent when you publish a post the proper way. Maybe there's some sort of mechanism to actually prevent this, to avoid spam.

I can imagine them generating a token everytime you open the textarea which validates the post etc.

Try to go through the whole process, and check what kind of cookies and headers they generate before just trying to post and see if you are lucky.

Comment: i am taking help from https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin with php Localhost.

Comment: Great, I hope you are lucky with this :)

Comment: Please Check   LinkedIn has removed access to groups from its free API. You can read about it here. It appears that you need to join one of the LinkedIn Developer Partnership Programs.   on  https://www.drupal.org/node/2488664.   I am still trying to solve issue.

Comment: Let me know if I can help you :)

Comment: Click on https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition  check and read  Your API call will return a 403 Forbidden error if you do not have the appropriate admin permission to interact with the target company.  these lines may be u get idea.